# Ansible playbook with loop double iterates the task on hosts

Tags: ansible

The playbook copies local files to servers, and then changes the permissions of one of the files:

```
- hosts: servers
  tasks:
    - include_vars: certs-list.yml

    - name: Transfer files
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.src_folder }}"
        dest: "{{ item.dest_folder }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item.dest_server }}"
      loop: "{{ certs }}"
      register: certificate_copied

    - name: Ensure privkey.pem right permissions
      file:
        path: "{{ item.dest_folder }}privkey.pem"
        mode: '600'
      with_items: "{{ certs }}"
```

Here I do specify a list, which file goes to which server:

```
#certs-list.yml
certs:
  - name: minio box1-1
    src_folder: certificates/com/xxx/box/1/
    dest_server: host-101.xxx.com
    dest_folder: /tmp/box1/
  - name: minio box1-2
    src_folder: certificates/com/xxx/box/2/
    dest_server: host-202.xxx.com
    dest_folder: /tmp/box2/
```

Here is my hosts inventory

```
[servers]
host-101.xxx.com
host-202.xxx.com
```

Here is the output:

```
PLAY [servers] *****************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [host-101.mydomain.com]
ok: [host-202.mydomain.com]

TASK [include_vars] ************************************************************
ok: [host-101.mydomain.com]
ok: [host-202.mydomain.com]

TASK [Transfer files] **********************************************************
changed: [host-101.mydomain.com -> host-101.mydomain.com] => (item={'name': 'minio box1-1', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/1/', 'dest_server': 'host-101.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box1/'})
changed: [host-202.mydomain.com -> host-101.mydomain.com] => (item={'name': 'minio box1-1', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/1/', 'dest_server': 'host-101.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box1/'})
changed: [host-101.mydomain.com -> host-202.mydomain.com] => (item={'name': 'minio box1-2', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/2/', 'dest_server': 'host-202.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box2/'})
ok: [host-202.mydomain.com -> host-202.mydomain.com] => (item={'name': 'minio box1-2', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/2/', 'dest_server': 'host-202.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box2/'})

TASK [Ensure privkey.pem right permissions] ************************************
changed: [host-101.mydomain.com] => (item={'name': 'minio box1-1', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/1/', 'dest_server': 'host-101.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box1/'})
failed: [host-202.mydomain.com] (item={'name': 'minio box1-1', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/1/', 'dest_server': 'host-101.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box1/'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"dest_folder": "/tmp/box1/", "dest_server": "host-101.mydomain.com", "name": "minio box1-1", "src_folder": "certificates/com/mydomain/box/1/"}, "msg": "file (/tmp/box1/privkey.pem) is absent, cannot continue", "path": "/tmp/box1/privkey.pem", "state": "absent"}
failed: [host-101.mydomain.com] (item={'name': 'minio box1-2', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/2/', 'dest_server': 'host-202.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box2/'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"dest_folder": "/tmp/box2/", "dest_server": "host-202.mydomain.com", "name": "minio box1-2", "src_folder": "certificates/com/mydomain/box/2/"}, "msg": "file (/tmp/box2/privkey.pem) is absent, cannot continue", "path": "/tmp/box2/privkey.pem", "state": "absent"}
changed: [host-202.mydomain.com] => (item={'name': 'minio box1-2', 'src_folder': 'certificates/com/mydomain/box/2/', 'dest_server': 'host-202.mydomain.com', 'dest_folder': '/tmp/box2/'})

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
host-101.mydomain.com : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host-202.mydomain.com : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The playbook iterates the task on each host 2 times!

The copy process goes well and the right files are copied to the right server, even when it is iterated wrongly.

But through the permissions task, the playbook tries to find all copied files on all hosts.

I would be very thankful for the help.

Comment: `The playbook iterates the task on each host 2 times!` <= If you expected something else you misunderstood how ansible loops / inventory work. You have 2 hosts in your inventory. You play the task on those two hosts using a list you include in a global scope which has 2 elements. That makes 2 iterations on each host. The result you get is totally expected. The way you delegate here does not make much sense. If you want to copy different files to different servers just make different definitions for each server in your inventory. The next error is just a consequence of your miss-usage.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I'm the guilty one: because I considered it was basically caused by a typo. I totally admit this is challengeable in this case. Since you gave a possible solution to manage with the given datastructure, I just retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate selected items only, e.g. given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host-101.xxx.com ansible_host=10.1.0.61
host-202.xxx.com ansible_host=10.1.0.62
```

and the tree

```
shell> tree box/
box/
├── 1
│   └── privkey.pem
└── 2
    └── privkey.pem
```

The play

```yaml
- hosts: host-101.xxx.com,host-202.xxx.com
  vars:
    certs:
      - name: minio box1-1
        src_folder: box/1/
        dest_server: host-101.xxx.com
        dest_folder: /tmp/box1/
      - name: minio box1-2
        src_folder: box/2/
        dest_server: host-202.xxx.com
        dest_folder: /tmp/box2/
  tasks:
    - name: Transfer files
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.src_folder }}"
        dest: "{{ item.dest_folder }}"
      loop: "{{ certs|selectattr('dest_server', 'eq', inventory_hostname) }}"

    - name: Ensure privkey.pem right permissions
      file:
        path: "{{ item.dest_folder }}privkey.pem"
        mode: '0600'
      loop: "{{ certs|selectattr('dest_server', 'eq', inventory_hostname) }}"
```

will copy the files to the remote nodes and change the mode

```
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.61 ls -la /tmp/box1/
total 26
drwxr-xr-x   2 admin  wheel   3 Aug 15 14:53 .
drwxrwxrwt  11 root   wheel  12 Aug 15 14:53 ..
-rw-------   1 admin  admin   0 Aug 15 14:53 privkey.pem

shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.62 ls -la /tmp/box2/
total 26
drwxr-xr-x   2 admin  wheel   3 Aug 15 14:53 .
drwxrwxrwt  11 root   wheel  12 Aug 15 14:53 ..
-rw-------   1 admin  admin   0 Aug 15 14:53 privkey.pem
```